# Murphy theorem A.1 about seminorms and continuity

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

I wish to prove that if a functional $\tau$ on some vector space $X$ is continuous in a locally convex topology (meaning one generated by some family of seminorms $\Gamma$) then there is a constant $M$, (possibly dependent on $n$) we have for any $x \in X$ and some $n\in\mathbb{N}$)

$$|\tau(x)|<M \max_{1<j<n} p_j(x)$$

The proof ([Murphy](https://books.google.dk/books/about/C_Algebras_and_Operator_Theory.html?id=omviBQAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y) page 267) goes as follows
The set $S:=\{x\in X \ |\tau(x)|<1\}$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in $X$. This is pretty obvious. Then we say there are semi-norms $p_1...p_n$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that $U(\epsilon, p_1...p_n)\subseteq S$ where the $U(\epsilon, p_1...p_n)=\{u\in X| p_j(u)<\epsilon \ \ j\in \{1,...n\} \}$.

But then he says that for $p=\max_{1<j<n} p_j$ if $p(x)<\epsilon$ then it implies $|\tau(x)|<1$. I'm confused about what this means, surely not that the fact that all of the seminorms in this neighbourhood that we defined *post factum*  somehow implies that the norm is indeed less than one (since it is simply a thing we chose to begin with arbitrarily).

What is the meaning of this implication?

Comment: Please provide additional detail. What is $M$? A constant $>0$? What is the index $n$ in the max of your first equation? What are the $p_j$? Members of the family $\Gamma$? What is $U(\varepsilon, p_1, \dots , p_n)$?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are writing things might be confusing you.

The situation is that you have a continuous linear functional $\tau$. The claim is that then one can find $M>0$ and seminorms $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ such that $$|\tau(x)|\leq M\,\max\{p_1(x),\ldots,p_n(x)\}. $$

For this one defines the set $S$ as you mention, which is open by hypothesis since $\tau$ is continuous. This means, as you say, that you can find a basic neighbourhood $U(\epsilon; p_1,\ldots,p_n)\subset S$. He puts $$ p(x)=\max\{p_1(x),\ldots,p_n(x)\}. $$
If $p(x)<\epsilon$, this means that $p_j(x)<\epsilon$ for all $j$, and thus $x\in U(\epsilon;p_1,\ldots,p_n)$, which is a subset of $S$. So we have that $x\in S$ and this means that $|\tau(x)|<1$.

Comment: What I don't understand is that since $p(x)<\epsilon$ which in turn means for all the $j$'s we have $p_j(x)<\epsilon$ is it just saying that if $x\in U(\epsilon; p_1...p_n)$ then $x\in S$ (where $S$ is characterized by the fact that $|\tau(x)|<1$) ?
or is it saying something else? It seems to be trivial that if $x\in U$ then $x\in S$ simply due to the fact that we defined that $U\subseteq S. Probably the point is something else. Sorry for my confusion

Comment: Yes, it is trivial once you know what the basic neighbourhoods look like. The argument works exactly the same way that one proves that a continuous linear map on a normed space is bounded. Not entirely sure what you expect.